# Cannot update or upgrade ubuntu desktop 14.04. Stuck

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

```
****@****-Inspiron-3537:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for ****: 
Err ://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       

Err ://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                     
  Unable to connect to 192.168.10.1:8080:
Ign s://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Err ://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              

Err ://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      

Err ://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    

Err ://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
  Unable to connect to 192.168.10.1:8080:
Err ://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg                    
  Unable to connect to 192.168.10.1:8080:
Err ://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg                  
  Unable to connect to 192.168.10.1:8080:
Err ://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease                             

Err ://repo.steampowered.com precise Release.gpg                           
  Unable to connect to 192.168.10.1:8080:
Err ://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease 

Err ://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 192.168.10.1:8080:
3% [Working].
```

Is my network not accepting ubuntu updates or is ubuntu server down?